# Import Cucumber results to Jira/Xray

Tags: groovy, cucumber, jira, jira-xray

I am able to run the Cucumber/groovy (with maven/pom.xml) test locally. I'm trying to import the test results (results.jon) generated by cucumber to Jira with Xray.

I'm unable to find the steps or procedures required for this. The only source found: https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results
but not applicable to my project. There is no CICD yet at the moment. Is there any way to generate results/reports imported to Jira every time I run a test/multiple tests?

Comment: You're on the wrong page: https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResults-REST-CucumberJSONresults

Answer (score 0):

For Gherkin-based frameworks, such as Cucumber, you can't simply submit the results. This is because Xray needs to have the Gherkin phrases, which cannot be inferred from the results file.
So you need to choose one of the [possible cucumber flows](https://docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62267221#TestinginBDDwithGherkinbasedframeworks(e.g.Cucumber)-Workflows). You need to either choose Xray as the master for the edition of Cucumber scenarios, or you need to use Git/SVN for that and then synch them to Xray.
These steps are detailed in the previous link.
You can see some useful tutorials [here](https://docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62269709).
There are some cucumber specific tutorials, such as [this one](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Cucumber+in+Java), but they're not fully detailed. You can see a more [technically detailed tutorial for Serenity BDD](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Serenity+BDD+and+Cucumber+in+Java) that make those steps more visible, for the two different flows (you'll need then to adapt it to cucumber specifics, but the principles are the same).